# How to prefix URLs specified by Spring MVC's @RequestMapping annotation?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, activiti

This question is a generalized version of [How do I change the Spring MVC servlet mapping for only Activiti REST endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351584/how-do-i-change-the-spring-mvc-servlet-mapping-for-only-activiti-rest-endpoints), but unfortunately it does not have an answer, so I am trying here to rephrase it into a pure Spring MVC question.

I am using Activiti BPM (6.0.0.4) which provides a starter for integration with Spring Boot (1.5.). Among other things it has a nice feature of exposing its functionality via REST, that is, one can add `activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api` to his POM and get a bunch of REST endpoints in his app.

These endpoints do not have a common root URL which poses certain problems during a configuration of security (I am using my own Spring Security settings and not the one provided by `activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api`. Therefore I would like to prefix all URLs served by controllers located in `org.activiti` package with a certain common URL segment. That is, I have all URLs of my app grouped under

```
http://host:port/contextPath/bpm
```

and default use of `activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api` creates

```
http://host:port/contextPath/deployments
http://host:port/contextPath/repository
...
```

but I would like to access them as

```
http://host:port/contextPath/bpm/native/deployments
http://host:port/contextPath/bpm/native/repository
...
```

As I see it, one way is to modify URLs when they are processed by `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, so I would appreciate any help with any of the following:

1. How to provide my version of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`?
2. Or better - how to plug into the process of URL-to-handler methods mapping?
3. Any other way which solves the problem described.